# Who exactly is "she" here?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-bourne-legacy

In *The Bourne Legacy* (2012), Byer decides to eliminate all Outcome assets. He orders new meds distributed
to the agents. He learns that both Numbers Three and Five are at the same location,
and dispatches a U-CAV drone aircraft to kill both agents but only Number 5 evade the
attack. Below is the transcript of controller of U-CAV drone aircraft on a
radio scanner:

> OFFICER: What's **she** doing?
>
> spec: **She**'s playing it back.
>
> OFFICER: I don't want to wait on **her**. We're going to have to come
> around.

Head of operation is Retired Air Force colonel Eric Byer.
There are **no females** present in this operation to take out Outcome assets.

Who exactly is "she" here?

Comment: The  is definitely a female character somewhere ... earlier in the same sequence you get "PILOT: Is she gonna cIear us here?".  From these phrases - its someone in charge of the entire operation.

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Who exactly is "she" here?

It's the **off-screen** mission commander referred to as "Solo" in the dialogue.

It's clear that the drone operation is reporting to someone they call "Solo" and, from the dialogue "Solo" is female.

Who "Solo" is not mentioned or, particularly, relevant.